# Thoughts on almost everywhere concept

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $X\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ and $f$ a measurable function. Suppose that I find: $f=0$ a.e. on $X$ and $f\neq 0$ a.e. on $X$. I believe that it is not a contradiction itself if $\mu(X)=0$. On the other hand, if $\mu(X)>0$, then
$$X=(X\cap\{f=0\})\cup (X\cap \{f\neq 0\})$$
implying $\mu (X)\leq 0,$
using the subadditivity of the measure. Indeed, this is a contradiction.

Are these ideas correct?

For example, if $X=\emptyset$, then $f=0$ a.e. on $X$ and $f\neq 0$ a.e. on $X$ would be vacuously true.

Comment: Seems fine. You don't even need X to be a subset of the reals.

Comment: thanks for the feedback